# Qual é mais performático - foreach ou array_map?

Tags: php

Qual de ambos são mais performáticos, foreach?

```php
foreach ($example as $val) $ex[] = str_replace(...);
```

ou

```php
$ex = array_map(function ($val) {
    return str_replace(...);
}, $example);
```

Acredito que seja o foreach, se for em quais caso devo utilizar o `array_map` e porque?

Qual de ambos segue melhor boas práticas de programação, ou não se encaixa neste escopo?

Comment: Sabes as diferenças entre os dois? sabes a razão de usar array_map para mapear uma array? (pergunto para podermos responder de forma adaptada ao teu conhecimento atual)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O problema a vezes é confundir o propósito de cada coisa.

`array_map` tem inúmeras funcionalidades, que vão além das apresentadas nos exemplos da pergunta.

`array_map` tem como finalidade mapear um `array` baseando-se numa função passada por `callback`.

Exemplo:

```
  array_map('trim', [' wallace ', ' bacco ', ' guilherme ']);
```

Resultado:

```
  ['wallace', 'bacco', 'guilherme']
```

Observe que a função `trim` foi chamado para cada item do `array`.

Nesse caso, se for comparar com `foreach`, pensaria na praticidade (e não somente em performance), pois se fosse fazer com `foreach`, esse código ficaria assim:

```
$arr = [' wallace ', ' bacco ', ' guilherme '];

foreach ($arr as &$value) $value = trim($value);
```

Então, você tem que ter em mente que a finalidade/propósito de cada um é diferente.

Outro exemplo para você entender isso é: Já se perguntou por quê no `array_map` o callback é passado como argumento primeiro que o `array`? É porque `array_map` permite múltiplos `arrays` - coisa que diferenciaria muito do `foreach`.

Veja:

```
array_map(function ($v1, $v2, $v3) {
       echo $v1, $v2, $v3;
}, ['a', 'b', 'c'], [1, 2, 3], ['@', '!', '&']);
```

O resultado seria:

```
'a1@'
'b1!'
'c3&'
```

Ou seja, com `array_map` você tem a possibilidade de mapear um ou mais `array`, e não só mapear apenas um.

**NOTA**: No exemplo acima, eu utilizei `echo` dentro do callback de `array_map`, mas não é algo que seja muito útil de se fazer com `array_map`.

No final das contas, eu fiz esses exemplos com `array_map` apenas para entender que não há necessidade de comparar `foreach`  com `array_map`, uma vez que os mesmos têm finalidade diferentes.

Você poderia, por exemplo, querer comparar `array_map` com `array_walk`, mas se você ver a finalidade de cada um, você vai ver que não fazem a mesma coisa.

Então minha conclusão é: Use `array_map` para mapear, e  `foreach`, para percorrer o `array`.